# How to invoke Tcl procedure at script start

Tags: tcl

I have a tcl script, that has the toplevel "." with a button.
It is possible to put this toplevel . inside a procedure, and when i start my script, the procedure will be invoked?
Exemp:

```
Menu
proc Menu { } {
    wm title . "Menu"
    ttk::button .b -width 30 -text close -command {exit}
    grid configure .b -row 0 -column 0 -sticky nw -padx 10 -pady 10 
}
```

I'm getting "invalid command name "Menu" (error)".

Comment: Just move the line calling `Menu` to the end - you can't call a proc before you have defined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl literally runs commands in the order you specify. Put the call to `Menu` after the call to `proc Menu` to make it.

And *if it is a one-shot command,* use an applied lambda so you don't pollute your namespace or have to use hacks with `rename`:

```
apply {{} {
    # All the local variables you could ever want are in here
    wm title . "Menu"
    set btn [ttk::button .b -width 30 -text close -command {exit}]
    grid configure $btn -row 0 -column 0 -sticky nw -padx 10 -pady 10 
}}
```